# Do i need add a capacitor on this current follower?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current

[image]

Hi,guys. I am making a current follower. I want to know the difference between the circuit with and without that capacitor.(I forget to change the value of each component, just ignore that).

Comment: A voltage follower is voltage in, voltage out. So in that context a current follower is current in, current out. This is known as a current mirror. What you have is current in, voltage out. So I would call this a **current to voltage converter** or a **transimpedance amplifier**.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments by FakeMoustache, what you have really shown is a transimpedance amplifier. You need a load to draw current from the opamp to get a current output. Even then the output current is not part of the feedback loop and therefore not "controlled" by the opamp.

The following answer is about the transimpedance amplifier circuit you have drawn:

Speaking from a system point of view (neglecting the limited bandwidth of the opamp) this is the difference between a frequency independent amplifier and a first order low pass with cutoff frequency at 
$$ f_\text{cutoff} = \frac{1}{2\pi R C}$$

From an electronics perspective you can also say that the circuit with the capacitor provides more negative feedback at high frequencies, making it more stable by providing a dominant pole and therefore increasing phase margin.

If you are wondering whether you need the capacitor, you can reserve a place for the capacitor and see whether the circuit is stable without one. If not, you can add the capacitor later on. If you are using SMD components, you can also solder the capacitor on top of the resistor, but I would not call this recommended practice except for some RF circuits.

If you are looking for a theoretical solution, you should lookup phase margin (or gain margin) calculations as well as theorems about circuit stability.

Comment: Thank you! so, I think I should test it with an oscilloscope

Comment: That's a way to do it. If your system allows it, it is best to supply a square wave signal at the input and look for overshoot at the output. If it becomes excessive, thats a strong indicator you are close to the stability limit.

Comment: Well,I test the circuit today. I supply a square wave at the input with 1k Hz and 1V. The output is about 1.7V. So that means I have to add a negative feedback capacitor. How can i determine the value of the capacitor if the resistor is 8.2k Ohm.

Comment: The amplitude is not overly important. Especially since you have shown a transimpedance amplifier, which has a _current_ input. You need an oscilloscope and look for excessive overshoot: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overshoot_(signal) If you only get a little overshoot, it will most likely not hurt your system. For the capacitor (if really needed), start in the 10 pF range and go up if needed.